# find number of places an alphabet to be shifted to make it alaphabetical order in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Here let us consider a string 'images'

original string is `str = 'images'`
alphabetical order is s`tr = 'aegims'`

to get this alphabetical order we shifted 'a' two places forward (i.e a) and 'e' to three places forward(i.e ae) and 'g' to one place forward (i.e aeg)
and 'i' to three places backward(i.e aegi)

so when user enters a letter we need to display the number of places it shifted

for suppose if user enters letter 'e' we need to print output as 3 places shifted

Comment: The question is not clear.

Comment: i have edited my question please check  it now

Comment: Yes, but it still is not clear what you are asking. It reads like a quote from a homework assignment. That is not a StackOverflow question. Please show what you tried as a [mre]. Describe where you are stuck, the symptoms of your codes failure. What is the desired output? What is the output you get? That way you can focus on the specific programming problem you encountered while trying yourself.

Comment: You should probably also decide on the programming language (version) you want to use. Doing this in two versions is probably unneeded and doing it so that both versions accept the same code probably introduces unnecessary complication.

Comment: What if there are multiple of the same letter ? What should be the output

Comment: If the letter is "m", do you want something like the result of `'aegims'.index('m') - 'images'.index('m')`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to code something like this:

```py
class Word():
    def __init__(self, word='') -> None:
        self.initial = word
        self.final = ''
        self.char_shift = {}
        self.__alphabetize()
        self.__calculate_shift()
    
    def __alphabetize(self) -> None:
        word = list(self.initial)
        #sort 
        counter = 0
        sorted = False
        
        while not sorted:
            #assume already sorted
            sorted = True
            for i in range(len(word)-1-counter):
                #check if actually sorted
                if word[i] > word[i+1]:
                    #set sorted
                    sorted = False
                    #swop
                    temp = word[i]
                    word[i] = word[i+1]
                    word[i+1] = temp
                
            #increase loop count
            counter += 1
        
        for char in word: self.final += char      
    
    def __calculate_shift(self) -> None:  
        for char in self.initial:
            self.char_shift[char] = abs(self.final.index(char) - self.initial.index(char))
```

It made more sense to make it a class, though functional would also work. Here are my inputs and outputs:

```py
word1 = Word('images')
print(word1.final)
print(word1.initial)
print(word1.char_shift['e'])
```

Output

```
aegims
images
3
```